# mongoid adding additional results to a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

So in Mongoid, I am sending as JSON a series of custom report templates. But the client also has some report types, which are always included.

**So a User has many Groups and each group has many ReportTemplates**

So when I run @user.report_templates I am given a hash like so ->

```
id: "the-snake-report"
name: "The Snake Report"
icon: null
location: null
active: "2014-06-20"
-field_templates: [
-{
-_id: {
$oid: "5391794d4d6163fcea360000"
}
mandatory: false
name: "How long was it?"
options: null
}
-{
-_id: {
$oid: "5391794d4d6163fcea370000"
}
mandatory: false
name: "Did it have any legs?"
options: null
}
-{
-_id: {
$oid: "5391794d4d6163fcea380000"
}
mandatory: false
name: "Did it any languages?"
-options: [
"English"
"Spanish"
"French"
]
}
]
}
-{
id: "bad-kids"
name: "Bad kids "
icon: null
location: null
active: "2014-06-19"
-field_templates: [
-{
-_id: {
$oid: "539167714d6163fcea2b0000"
}
mandatory: false
name: "fish"
-options: [
"one"
"two"
"three"
]
}
-{
-_id: {
$oid: "539167714d6163fcea2c0000"
}
mandatory: false
name: "The cat in the hat?"
options: null
}
-{
-_id: {
$oid: "539167714d6163fcea2d0000"
}
mandatory: true
name: "Are you ok?"
options: null
}
-{
-_id: {
$oid: "539167714d6163fcea2e0000"
}
mandatory: true
name: "Is it a house?"
-options: [
"A car"
"a boat"
]
}
]
}
```

etc. 
So I would like to take that method such as @user.report_templates.includes(ReportTemplate.simple_report)

and have it include onto that hash. (Instead of keeping it in the DB, I would prefer to keep it as a method) 
But I am not really sure what to do with the error:

```
TypeError: wrong argument type Hash (expected Module)
```

So I have also tried to make a helper (module) called SimpleReport

```
@user.report_templates.includes(ReportTemplate.simple_report)
```

But then I get a MOPED query

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I figured it out. 
Basically taking the results.to_json   and appending onto it my results.

> render json: @template.as_json << ReportTemplate.simple_report